# How can I make a scoreboard variable not go over a certain number?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need to have a scoreboard variable that can count up to 9 and add one whenever a player kills a player. How can I set a limit to the scoreboard variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set an intrinsic limit to a scoreboard objective (i.e. limit it automatically), but there are several things you can do. In the following, I'll assume an objective called SCORE, which should not go above 10.

#### Double-check the need

If the score is not on display, a higher value than 10 might not hurt the mechanics at all. `@a[score_SCORE_min=10]` works for all scores greater or equal to 10, be it 10, 11, 12 and 6871946.

#### Prevent increasing it in the first place

If your score is incremented manually, e.g. with a `dummy` type objective and `scoreboard players add`, you can often simply prevent the score from increasing higher than you want with something like

`scoreboard players add @a[score_SCORE=9] SCORE 1`

Be careful though, as you might then end up increasing another player's score instead! To prevent this, make sure the player whose score should increase is *uniquely* targeted with your target selector and/or his data tags.

#### Reset it to MAX if greater

If the above two points fail, it's time to add another command altogether, to reset it to the maximum value if a player goes above. This works for all sorts of objectives, including automatically incrementing ones like `stat.X.Y` or `deathCount`. Create a clock (20Hz./Repeat command blocks are ideal), or simply use the one you use anyway (place it before the cap is needed in your commands)

```
scoreboard players set @a[score_SCORE_min=11] SCORE 10
```

This also works for lower boundaries, which can be useful in some cases:

```
scoreboard players set @a[score_SCORE=-1] SCORE 0
```

In both of these cases, changing the max can be annoying, since you have to manually edit the commands, and you cannot easily set the cap with commands.

#### Dynamic solution

A more sophisticated version would be to use a dummy player - let's call him #MAX (the # makes this name illegal for real players) - and `scoreboard players operation`. Instead of the command above, use

```
scoreboard players operation @a SCORE < #MAX SCORE
```

Every player's SCORE is now set to the minimum of their own, or #MAX's score. To set the maximum, simply assign #MAX a score:

```
scoreboard players set #MAX SCORE 10
```

Similarly, a bottom cap can be set (dummy player called #MIN)

```
scoreboard players operation @a SCORE > #MIN SCORE
```

Comment: The "Reset it to MAX if greather" works like a charm for this problem because I want people with 12,17,200 kills to be able to use the kill streak ability that comes with 9 kills.